# Magento2: Custom module development and DI

Tags: php, dependency-injection, magento2

I started implementation of new module in **Magento2** and since that time I have more questions than answers.

I successfully created my own module and it seems to be working, but not really. I'm using my own controllers and wanted to implement my own layout, with some external (*not local*) JS/CSS files.

What I firstly stuck with is **adding some external JS/CSS to the page**. It occurred to be not so easy as I thought. I've read many articles on how it could be done, but none of them worked for me. I don't want to alter any theme, I just want to use my custom page (*possibly without theming at all*).

Furthermore I created another action (*same as working `HelloWorld` example*) in my module `app/code/MyModule/Product/Controller/Api/Index.php` which extends right class etc. etc., but again - *not working*. What I was receiving is next error:

> Recoverable Error: **Argument 1** passed to ...\Api\AbstractApiAction::__construct() **must be an instance of** Magento\Framework\App\Action\**Context**, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\**ObjectManager given**, called in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 97 and defined in app/code/.../Api/AbstractApiAction.php on line 24

What was my surprise when I discovered that it will not work unless I recompile my DI container with `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. I think it is not worth saying that this process takes a bit of time. And when I'm creating new action I ought to go and do `setup:di:compile` to be able to develop on it further.

I fully disabled caching in admin area.

---

Now I want to clear several questions:

1. How I can add external JS/CSS files to my custom page (*of custom controller*).
2. Is there any way of developing smth. without constantly recompiling DI container? *Or am I missing smth.?*
3. According to question above, what does really `Developer mode` means in Magento2, I remember that it disables caching etc., but the codebase is not auto-regenerated or am I missing smth. again?

Answer (score 3):

As to di compiling, you do not need to run this command when in developer mode. If there is var/di directory magento will read configuration from it but you can safely delete it and it will work fine, only slightly slower as all di preferences need to be read from files. The error you've seen was due to the fact that magento generates interceptor classes to allow use of plugins. Those classes are created in var/generation and contains di constructor information for the autoloader. When you change your constructor for the class that was generated in previous request it will break. If you see such error in the future simply delete var/cache, var/generation and var/di (if exists) and refresh the page.